# Weak password hash + strong rate limiter = secure?

Tags: hash, password-cracking, brute-force, microservices, cache

I have a microservice which sole purpose is to serve as a cache for other microservices. The point of the cache is to speed up processing, but the strong password hash algo counter that purpose. (Company policy require all service to be secure even internal ones)

I am considering to deliberately weaken the hash algo to speed up cached lookups, but also add a rate limiter in case someone are able to access the caching service and attempt to brute force access to steal cached info.

Will this solution serve the intended purpose or would it introduce a security vulnerability?

Comment: Can I access the caching service and download hashes?

Comment: This is why API's typically use short-lived access tokens.  Once the client authenticates with a long-lived token (or password), the client is provided with a short-lived token which the client uses to authenticate on subsequent requests.  These authentications are very fast and inexpensive, because the short-lived token can be hashed with a very fast hashing algorithm (e.g. one round of sha256, or similar).

Comment: Often, JWT tokens are used for this purpose. The token can be cryptographically signed so that it can't be forged or modified, and this signature is cheap to validate. However, tokens cannot be revoked, so they should only be valid for a short duration. An even simpler technique is a kind of session cookie, essentially a long random token. Instead of doing cryptography, the server would check if that session exists in the session database, and to which client it belongs. Regardless of your auth methods, rate limiting is a good idea.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Why would you want to go against compliance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slow password hashing and rate limiting mostly address different problems. The former is mostly to prevent *offline* hash cracking. The latter is for brute-force and DoS prevention. You actually need rate limiting in combination with strong password hashing, otherwise an attacker can simply make your server spend all its resources on hashing passwords and have none left for any other task.

Obviously, this means that you should not use a weak (fast/cheap) password hash, even if you have rate limiting (unless you don't care about offline attacks at all, which implies both trusting the server admin with all user passwords and being sure that password hashes won't leak via e.g. database backups getting stolen/compromised).

However, the biggest problem with your design is that apparently you're using a system that sends the password on every single request? Don't do that. It has horrible performance, and in some cases increases risk of password exposure (depending on implementation and other details). Instead, do one of the following (presented in no particular order):

- Use API keys instead of passwords. These are machine-generated and cryptographically random with high entropy, so unlike passwords, there is no need for a slow hash function; using a single round of a fast hash (e.g. SHA2 or SHA3 families) is fine. You don't even need salt; there's no possibility of feasible rainbow tables and no real risk of collisions.
- An alternative form of API keys is using them as the key to HMAC the request, and sending the MAC but never sending the key itself in any form (this is what e.g. Amazon's AWS SigV4 does). This has some weaknesses - the keys can't be hashed on the server - but it's more secure if you're worried about network traffic exposure (e.g. TLS termination). On the other hand, given the security policy you mentioned, probably that's not an issue and you should just use TLS.
- Have users log in (with slow password hashing), and then generate them a high-entropy random session token. Store this token (optionally with a single round of fast hashing) in a DB or cache (for smallish user counts you can store them in-process on the server) and look it up when requests come in. Simple, classic, highly secure. Makes scaling a little harder but that's probably not an issue for an internal tool unless you're running on a really weak server.
- Have users log in and then generate them a short-lived JWT (JSON Web Token) signed with a server-stored secret, and a high-entropy random session token. Store the latter in the DB (after a fast hash), and have the client send the JWT on every request; you can verify it without hitting the DB at all. However, because the JWTs are not stored on the server, there's no good way to revoke them, so they need to be short-lived. Clients can get a new one without signing in again using the refresh token, which works like a normal session token but is only used for the specific purpose of getting a new JWT (and potentially a new refresh token at the same time).
- Either of the "have users log in" options, but with corporate or external SSO (e.g. OIDC, SAML, Kerberos/Active Directory, etc.) instead of you handling passwords yourself at all. Reduces the number of places that user passwords ever get sent and streamlines the user's login experience, at the cost of complicating the login flow from your end.
- Use mutual TLS (TLS with client certificates). Especially if your company already provisions users/machines with their own client certificate, this is a fast and secure way to handle authentication (though you may need to cross-check with a corporate server to see if a user is authorized / still with the company, rather than trusting any cert issued by the internal CA). Cert validation is faster than secure password hashing but slower than fast hashes and can be slower than DB lookups, so if you want to make this option fast, use the mTLS client cert only for login, then generate a token (random or HMAC-signed JWT+refresh) for the session.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the direct answer to the question about the strengths. But I'd suggest you to consider following, before you change hashing.

1. **Have you measured performance?** Is password hashing really a bottleneck? If the current response time of caching service is 0.100s and hashing time is 0.001s, then any acceleration of password hashing will give you very small improvement, less than 1% of the total response time. You decide, if reducing hashing time makes any sense.
2. **Brute-forcing via network is very inefficient.** The most of the time will be used for network, which will make brute-forcing very slow. Besides, the account will be usually locked after wrong password is provided many times. That's why, if the attacker gets access to your database with password hashes, brute-forcing will be done on some high performant devices on the attacker side, not by calling your service.
3. **Request rate limit can be a bottleneck.** Use rate limiting to prevent resource exhaustion and thus to prevent *denial of service*. You can set such limit that resources can be loaded up to 80%. If you set low request limit rate that is reached even at 1% of resource load, this will slow your other services down and will be effectively a bottleneck.

That's why I'd suggest you to consider other approaches, suggested by @amon and @mti2935, like JWT or session token.

Comment: It is the other way around, retrieving the value from the cache is about 1ms, but the current hashing method is about 100ms. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @JasperCiti: It would be helpful, if you put such important information in the question.